# Voltammogram during calibration is not smooth

Tags: electrochemistry, experimental-chemistry, analytical-chemistry, cyclic-voltammetry

During calibration for differential pulse voltammetry, the voltammogram obtained has two distinct peaks. I am not sure why I am getting two peaks in the range from $\pu{-0.6 V}$ to $\pu{-0.9 V}.$ I have used three electrode setup. I used screen printed carbon working electrode, platinum counter electrode and saturated calomel electrode as reference electrode. Mercuric chloride was used for deposition of mercury over the carbon working electrode.

The $y$ axis shows current, and the $x$ axis shows potential. This is just one example, similar types of voltammograms were obtained. The peak on the far right in the range of $\pu{0.09 V}$ might be of mercury. This is the voltammogram obtained for $\pu{0.1 ppm}$ cadmium nitrate standard solution.

[image: Voltammogram]

Comment: Do you mean in your question that you find extra peaks you are not able to assign?

Comment: @Jojostack Not related to this question, but your frequent title formatting: Chemistry SE  (in contrary to some other SE sites) strongly recommends plain text question titles without MathJax for index/search reasons and due possible displaying issues in question title lists.

Comment: @jojostack I am very new to voltammetry. I am using DPV to quantify cadmium in my sample. I am required to make a calibration curve of concentration vs peak current. However, i am getting double peaks. Which peak current value should i take?

Comment: Also, on increasing the concentration of cadmium, the smaller peak goes on increasing and the larger peak becomes smaller. Its strange. On increasing the concentration, the peak current should increase, shouldn't it ?

Comment: Cd peaks is the one near -0.745 E/V (as far as I know) is this what you were asking?

Comment: Okay, so the smaller peak. Alright, but what is the cause of peak splitting, given that i have used a standard solution of cadmium nitrate?